# Spinner: can't see the selected item

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

Hi so i made 3 spinners whit values but after i run the app and select one value, the spinner value changes but i can't see it. [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yaxu1.png) [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nMgY.png)

I selected the value 20 but in picture 2 i can't see the value
Here is my xml file code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/Spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=":" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/Spinner2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/Spinner3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my java class code:

```
spinerOra = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> AdaptorOra = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.ora , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    AdaptorOra.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinerOra.setAdapter(AdaptorOra);

    spinerMinute1 = findViewById(R.id.Spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> AdaptorMinute1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.minute1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    AdaptorMinute1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinerMinute1.setAdapter(AdaptorMinute1);

    spinerMinute2 = findViewById(R.id.Spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> AdaptorMinute2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.minute2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    AdaptorMinute2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinerMinute2.setAdapter(AdaptorMinute2);
```

What can i do so that the spinner will show me the selected value?

Answer (score 3):

So sometimes the answer can be something really stupid so I didn't notice that the text is white and the background is also white pff.... it took me 30 minutes to find the answer haha

Comment: Don't feel bad, sometimes people search on google only to read the answer to something that took even longer than 30 minutes of searching.. /facepalm.. thanks lol